# How to programmatically take a screenshot of an app in iOS with UIAlertController as the top controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, screenshot, uialertcontroller

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    static func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage? {
        guard let topController = UIApplication.getTopController() else { return nil }
        
        if let view = topController.view {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
            
            defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
            
            if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
                view.layer.render(in: context)
                let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                return screenshot
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly but the issue is when we have UIAlertController on top. I want to take a screenshot of the entire screen (not the status bar of course) but the controller as well as any alert controller that is presented on top. Right now the code is working fine if there is no alert controller on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the job, for iOS 13 with iPad not supporting multiple scenes.

```
func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage? {
    
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: window.bounds)
    let image = renderer.image { _ in
        window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    
    return image
}
```

Comment: UIApplication windows has been deprecated since iOS 15. Why not get the view controller's window directly?

Comment: UIAlertController is on top, I want the screenshot with the alert, meaning screenshot of screen, excluding status bar.

Comment: I understand that. I'm pointing out that you are not getting the window correctly.

Comment: Actually I am developing for iOS 13, sure you can provide the answer that supports iOS 15 along with this solution and I will mark it as answered, please do self check the solution first (in iOS 15), with uialertcontroller presented on top. Thanks

Comment: Even under iOS 13 your code can fail. Consider an application that supports multiple scenes on an iPad. Your code could easily reference the wrong window from the wrong scene. That's why `windows` was deprecated. It became obsolete and wrong even in iOS 13 but some reason it wasn't deprecated until iOS 15.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the function that might help

```
func captureScreenshot() -> UIImage? {
guard let keyWindowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    .filter({ $0.activationState == .foregroundActive })
    .first as? UIWindowScene else {
    return nil
}

guard let window = keyWindowScene.windows.first else {
    return nil
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return screenshotImage
```

}

Comment: UIApplication windows has been deprecated since iOS 15.

Answer (score -1):

The code you are using will only take a screenshot of the top-most view controller and not the elements display on top of it.

You could instead look into taking a snapshot of the key window:

```swift
let keyWindow = UIWindowScene().keyWindow!
let layer = keyWindow.layer
let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
...//rest of your code
```

Comment: Why would you create a new scene and try to capture its empty window?

Comment: @HangarRash This is just an example. The key window can be obtained also from other place.  I sharing example from SwiftUI application I used.

Comment: But it's not a valid example. Show a useful example that works. That would be more helpful than showing an example that doesn't work.